# Using xmlStar to get XML node attribute

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, rss

I'm trying to get XML values from a rss feed XML using [xmlStar](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/):

`https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UC16niRr50-MSBwiO3YDb3RA`

[image]

The XML paths are:

- `/feed/entry/title`
- `/feed/entry/yt:videoId`
- `/feed/entry/media:group/media:thumbnail/@url`

I've tried following the [doc and examples](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/docs.php) but I can extract nothing.

My goal is to print **all** `/entry` in `/feed/`. For example:

```
France paralysed by biggest strike in years - BBC News
6Mm1M-cdKqU
https://i3.ytimg.com/vi/6Mm1M-cdKqU/hqdefault.jpg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your xpath expressions to these, and see if that works:

```
//*[local-name()='feed']/*[local-name()='entry']/*[local-name()='title']/text()
//*[local-name()='feed']/*[local-name()='entry']/yt:videoId/text()
//*[local-name()='feed']/*[local-name()='entry']/media:group/media:thumbnail/@url
```

Comment: Perfect! `xml sel -t -v "<XPATH>" videos.xml`. Now, would it be possible to combine the 3 in 1 command so I get the results nested like my example?

Comment: @Azevedo - It's possible as an xpath expression, though I'm not sure xmlstarlet supports it; but try it anyway (warning: it's ugly...): `//*[local-name()='feed']/*[local-name()='entry']/(*[local-name()='title']/text(),yt:videoId/text(),media:group/media:thumbnail/@url)`

Comment: it makes perfect sense but xmlstar wont take the nested expression. The perfect scenario would be transforming the output in a `json`.

Comment: @Azevedo - Yes, it seems it only support xpath 1.0. See if you can use `xidel`; it support xpath 3.0 and should be able to take nested expressions.